# What could be the reasons for toggle display to cease working after toggling once?

Tags: jquery

I have a map application that uses jQuery to show/hide some map controls upon clicking of a button. Now, all the controls are working fine except for one - the pan_zoom control. The html elements for the map controls are added dynamically together with some inline styling:

```
<div class="pan_zoom" style="display: block; top: 4px">pan zoom button</div>
```

The pan_zoom control is hidden upon loading of the map with:

```
$('.pan_zoom').hide();
```

Upon clicking of the button, a function containing the following line is called:

```
$('.pan_zoom').toggle();
```

This function hide the pan_zoom control on the first click. However, it did not show the control on the next click.

I tested the above again, without hiding the pan_zoom control upon initialization. This time, toggling has no effect on the element.

What could be the possible reasons that is preventing the toggle function from working properly?

Note that I did not set any CSS display property for this element and that I can solve this problem by replacing the toggle function with:

```
if($('.pan_zoom').css('display') == 'block')
{
 $('.pan_zoom').hide();
}
else
{
 $('.pan_zoom').show();
}
```

What I am more interested is to find out why `toggle()` is not working properly.

The click handler is:

```
$('button[name="expand_map"]').click(toggleMap);
function toggleMap() {
....
 $('.pan_zoom, .and_other_controls').toggle();
}
```

Comment: Syntax problem? `top=4px` should be `top: 4px`.

Comment: oops, that is my typo. sorry, let me correct that.

Comment: Show us the code for the click event handler.  Are you sure the click event for the button is being fired?

Comment: Maybe replicate your problem in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @Lokase, yes, it is firing. The same function is used to toggle other controls successfully. I can't show the code because it is quite a chunk of it.

Comment: @Bruno, I tried JSfiddle which is ok. Posted here to see if anyone have encountered such problem before before because it involves the API which is difficult to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tricky one. I write it down here so that others who came across this will take a hard look at the computed element style. In my case, the computed height and width for the pan_zoom control element turns out to be 0 due to absolute positioning of divs within the control div. This in turn affects how jQuery `toggle()` function treat the display of the element.

I presume it considers elements with zero width and height to be equivalent to a hidden element and therefore does not hide it. One way to overcome this problem is to use `show()` / `hide()` as described in the question. Another less obvious way, in order to use `toggle()`, is to set a value for the width and height. With jQuery, this will be:

```
$('.pan_zoom').css({'height': '1px', 'width': '1px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, perhaps it will make a difference:

```
<div class="pan_zoom" style="display:none; top: 4px">pan zoom button</div>

// Comment out this line
//$('.pan_zoom').hide();

// Proceed as normal for the click handler
$('.pan_zoom').toggle();
```

Comment: I can't change the inline style which is added by the API itself.

Comment: Try changing the style attribute once the page has loaded: $('.pan_zoom').attr('style', 'display:none; top:4px;');

Comment: I don't think I can troubleshoot without seeing the click handler code.  I don't need to see the code inside the event handler just the trigger code (eg - $('my_element').click()... etct )

Comment: Shouldn't the syntax be like this: $('button[name="expand_map"]').click( toggleMap() );

Comment: Interesting.  Because without the trailing "()", javascript thinks you are attempting to evaluate a variable.  Take a look at this fiddle to get an idea of what I think is happening: http://jsfiddle.net/AZrj8/

Comment: It's different if you put an anonymous function inside the click handler. Without which, the function would run upon initialization instead of listening for the click.

Comment: Yep, your totally right ( I learn something new everyday).  Updated the jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/AZrj8/1/).  The toggle works as expected in the jsfiddle.  Is there anywhere else in your code that you are calling a toggle on the "pan_zoom" element?  Are there any over event triggers that are firing and causing the "pan_zoom" visibility state to change?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I managed to solve it. See my answer below.